# Find model instance from table name in Django

Tags: python, django, model, metaclass

I've the following table.

```
class TempTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'temp_table'
```

Now suppose I know the table name `temp_table`. Currently I'm using the following script to get the `model instance` from `table name`.

```
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models

all_models = get_models()
for item in all_models:
    if item._meta.db_table == 'temp_table':
        return item
```

Are there any better ways of achieving this..??

Comment: I believe there is not. `get_models()` returns iterable which is good for memory purposes and also this function is decorated with `@lru_cache`, so it shouldn't be heavy at all.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no backward mapping. The `db_table` also does not need to be unique in your project, just within one app. So a generic way is not even possible without the `app_label`.

Answer (score -1):

you can access the model instance from the model name like below also you check the table name but i think you do not need this;

```
        if hasattr("TempTable", "__class__"):
            mod = __import__("<your_app_name>.models", fromlist=["TempTable"])
            nclss = getattr(mod, "TempTable")
            # in here nclss is your model instance so you can use it
            # nclss.objects.all().order_by("id")
            return nclss
            # you can also check the table name but i think you did not need this
            if nclss._meta.db_table == "temp_table":
                return nclss
```

i hope it works for you